# Mysql single query to display the max points in table and points corresponding to a particular msisdn

Tags: mysql

I have a table which is having two columns msisdn,points.I require to display the max points in table and points corresponding to a particular msisdn through a single query.The query that i am using is based on sub queries and i don't think so that it is the most efficient way to do this.Guys kindly share an alternative optimized single query for this.

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_121314_point_base` (
  `msisdn` bigint(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `points` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  KEY `msisdn` (`msisdn`)
) ENGINE=INnoDB;
```

Current Query:

```
select (
select max(points) from tbl_121314_point_base ) as max_points,
(select points from tbl_121314_point_base where msisdn = 9024317476) as ori_points 
from tbl_121314_point_base limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can rewrite your query using cross join use `EXPLAIN` plan to see performance of both queries

```
select p.points ori_points ,
t.max_points
from tbl_121314_point_base p
where p.msisdn = 9024317476 
cross join(select max(points) max_points 
           from tbl_121314_point_base ) t
limit 1;
```